# Rename [errors-erratum] to [errata] with respective synonyms

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently we have a tag [errors-erratum](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/errors-erratum) with [erratum](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/erratum) being the sole synonym.
I see no reason to have tag with such a convoluted name and not use the synonym system for this.

I thus propose to:

- Rename the tag to [errata](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/errata).
- Create synonyms [errors](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/errors) or maybe [erratum](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/erratum) pointing to [errata](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/errata).

Is there any problem or better solution I am missing?

Answer (score 4):

I think the only potential problem is that “errors” might be misused for other types of mistakes, rather than for mistakes in publishing. Your solution of errata with the synonym erratum (no mention of “errors”) avoids this potential problem.

Comment: Mind that (at least in what I proposed), [errors] would still be a synonym pointing to [errata]. However, when entering tags, the asker will only see [errata], pretty much as they always see [errors-erratum] now.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Isn't the way synonyms work that someone will start writing "errors" and tag their question with it, and then that will silently convert to "errata"? That might not work well if they had a different type of error in mind.

Comment: It’s not really silent. Assuming the proposed change, if you type in `errors`, you get offered/shown [errata] with a note “also: **errors**”. If you ignore this, and leave `errors` standing, it would get converted once you submit the question. (Except for the last step, best test it yourself.) This slightly lowers the threshold in comparison to the existing situation where just leaving `errors` in the tag field would alert you that you are about to create a new tag (and, if applicable, that you lack the reputation for that).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Got it; as I very rarely ask questions I've mostly encountered this through users who have been very confused at why a tag they didn't think they added ended up on their question.

Comment: @BryanKrause: Those must be really typing without looking (or without Internet connection).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I just tested this out, and it seems clear to me where people would get confused. Let's say you are writing "errors" because that's the word that came to mind when you're thinking about mistakes on an exam, you see "errata" appear below but you don't select that tag, after all, your question isn't about "errata", so you don't click it. Then you'll see "[errors x]" as the tag, so it seems great, you've got the errors tag you wanted. Except...then you submit, and it will later say "errata". Yet you never chose that tag; it may have showed up, but you specifically did not select it.

Comment: @BryanKrause: I see. I made a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378550/255554) on this.